# date components in swift returns next year from end year date

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I'm trying to get year value of next year from it's end date.
Example now we have 2021, so I need 2022.

To get end of next year

```swift
let calendar = Calendar.current
let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())

let nextYear = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: today)
// Optional(2022-02-03 15:17:22 +0000)

var endOfNextYear = calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: nextYear!)?.end
// Optional(2022-12-31 23:00:00 +0000)
```

up this point it all works fine, but now when I want to get just the year value using `DateComponents` this is what happens

```swift
print(calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: endOfNextYear!).year)
// Optional(2023)
```

Why the year bumps up?

One observation I have is that if I'll subtract 1 second then the year is fine

```swift
endOfNextYear?.addTimeInterval(-1)
print(calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: endOfNextYear!).year)
// Optional(2022)
```

That made me think that maybe that's related to the zime zones since I'm in Warsaw 1 hour "above" the GMT but even if I set explicitly timezone wherever I can it's still the wrong year

```swift
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!
let components = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT"), year: 2021)
let d1 = calendar.date(from: components)
let d2 = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: d1!)
let d3 = calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: d2!)?.end
print(d3)
// Optional(2023-01-01 00:00:00 +0000)
```

Just to clarify I know I can take the year correctly from:

`print(calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: nextYear!).year)`

but I'm wondering why it bumps the year value when I'm using `end` property on `Date`

Comment: `2022-12-31 23:00:00 +0000` wouldn't that be midnight in your TimeZone? Meaning, it's already next year? No? `Calendar.current` is the culprit here. So the question is, which `Calendar` do you really want to use? Your local one?

Comment: Exactly! Tho afaik it's assigned by default to `Calendar.current` then later when I use `calendar.dateComponents` shouldn't it use the same calendar? Resulting in it's keeping 23:00:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alan's answer explains why your code is giving a value **two** years in the future.

Try this code instead:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())

let components = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 1) //Create a DateComponents containing 1 year.

//Get a date in next year
if let nextYearDate = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: today) {
    
    //Get the year value for next year.
    let nextYear = calendar.component(.year, from: nextYearDate)
    print(nextYear)
}
```

### Edit:

As to why using `dateInterval(of: .year, from:)` adds a year to your date, consider the following code:

```
if let thisYearInterval = calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: Date()) {
    let endOfYear = thisYearInterval.end
    let beginningOfYear = thisYearInterval.start
    print("year start = ", DateFormatter.localizedString(from: beginningOfYear, dateStyle:.short, timeStyle: .short))
    print("year end = ", DateFormatter.localizedString(from: endOfYear, dateStyle:.short, timeStyle: .short))
}
```

That outputs

```
year start =  1/1/21, 12:00 AM
year end =  1/1/22, 12:00 AM
```

It looks like it adds a full year to the starting date, so the .start and .end dates are actually always in different years.

It does seem odd. I would say it should add a year, minus one second.

Note that if you change the calculation of `endOfNextYear` from

```
let endOfYear = thisYearInterval.end
```

to

```
let endOfYear = thisYearInterval.end.addingTimeInterval(-0.01)
```

It then outputs

```
year start =  1/1/21, 12:00 AM
year end =  12/31/21, 11:59 PM
```

The way you wanted

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, but it's same as my note at the bottom of question, if I try to use end of next year it goes to 2023 too

Comment: When instead of using `nextYearDate` I'll use `calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: nextYearDate)?.end!`

Comment: Don't do that. Alan explained that that has the effect of adding 2 years to your starting date. Simply add a year to the current date and then getting the year component from the result.

Comment: Yup that I see, I'm trying to understand why it happens, now I found out that changing the order of these operation produces correct year, so if I first call the `dateInterval` then `date(byAdding:` it gives me 2022 (I'll update the question)

Comment: Okay it's not fixing the problem I made a mistake, tho still I don't understand why it's adding next year when I just want to access it's end

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer. Printing the start and end dates of the call to `dateInterval(of: .year, from:)` in localized format lets you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Okay so actually end of the year is start of new year > , <. Thanks for such a detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your `endOfNextYear` calculation is already producing next years value. The `dateInterval` is then adding a year onto the `endOfNextYear` value which makes it 2023

Basically both `calendar.date(byAdding` & `calendar.dateInterval(of:` are essentially adding an interval.

Comment: Not sure what you mean after calling `calendar.dateInterval(of:` I still have 2022. The moment it breaks is when I call the `end` property and operate on it