# Swift ui date formatting

Tags: swift, xcode, date, swiftui, formatter

I have dates in this format, these dates are taken from a json on http.

```
"2022-03-28T09:44:30Z"
```

The format I would like to have is this:

- If the date is today, print `Today, hh:mm`
- If the date is of type yesterday, print `Yesterday, hh:mm`
- If the date is after yesterday, print `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`

[image]

```swift
Table(repositories) {
...
TableColumn("Last updated"){
     Text($0.updated_at)
}
...
}
```

Comment: You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift) how to use the `DateFormatter`. Then, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66030777/date-components-in-swift-returns-next-year-from-end-year-date) for how to compare the dates with today or yesterday.

Comment: @HunterLion: I'm trying like this:

https://pastebin.com/SgBuwGuT
Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiUlA.png

Comment: in your comment, you are applying the formatter to the `Text`, while you should apply it to the variable.  Like this: `Text(formatter.string(from: $0.updated_at))`.

Comment: @HunterLion: error, Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with `Yesterday at 21:51` rather than `Yesterday, 21:51` create a date formatter and enable `doesRelativeDateFormatting`

```
let outputFormatter : DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
    formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    return formatter
}()
```

and create a function to convert the ISO8601 string

```
func convertISODate(_ isoString : String) -> String {
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    guard let date = formatter.date(from: isoString) else { return "Unknown date format" }
    return outputFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

and use it

```
TableColumn("Last updated"){
     Text(convertISODate($0.updated_at))
}
```

However I would put the entire conversion code into the model.

Side note: `doesRelativeDateFormatting` does not work with a custom date format specified in the `dateFormat` property.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: I can just do that: 'return outputFormatter.string(from: date).replacingOccurrences(of: " at", with: ",")'

Comment: With the following code it would be possible to manage also the following format `"2018-02-06T04:36:52.369420+00:00"`?

Comment: Yes, insert `formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]` after the `let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()` line. But not ***also***, it handles only ISO dates with fractional seconds.

Comment: But isn't there a way to make both formats work together?
Because if I use `formatOptions` it works with the second format but not the first.
If I don't use it, only the first format works.

Comment: Add an `if - else` expression and check the date. Set the format options of the formatter to the appropriate value.